# Lucene - Solr version compatibility

Tags: solr, lucene

I have an app the writes lucene indexes and is based on lucene 2.3.0.

Can I read those indexes using solr 3.5.0 and perform a distributed search? Or should I use a lower version of solr, so that the index reader is compatible with the index writer.

Would be great if somebody with prior exposure can advice!

Comment: Basically I want to know if lucene indexes of 2.3.0 and 3.5.0 are compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the Solr & Lucene are part of the same project. its recommended you use the same Solr and Lucene 3.5 version.

The index format must have changed between the Lucene releases and the indexes will surely be incompatible, if so.

But as you are building the index using Lucene and exposing it through Solr, you can check setting the luceneMatchVersion parameter accordingly in solrconfig.xml to see if it works.

```
<luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_30</luceneMatchVersion>
```